# How to match the two datasets on Electoral bonds given by SBI?

Tags: dataset, data-mining, data-cleaning, feature-extraction, finance

Just stumbled across the Electoral bond dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shaundanielll/electoral-bond-data-state-bank-of-india

There are two csvs- One contains Encashment data(Date of encashment, Name of political party, amount) and the other contains Purchase data(date of purchase, Purchaser name, amount). However no unique key is provided to map these two

Answer (score 1):

I was about to ask same question here. IMO It's a very good idea, to present some methodology that can analyse this data in a way it helps people.

What are the things we will need, to find, say a scenario on how related the data are (given there is no direct relation between the CSV files):

1. The data of `amount by Parties by date` (given)
2. The data of `amount by Companies by date` (given)
3. The data of `all tenders by allotment type and winner company` for said time period
4. The profitability report of said companies for the said time period (more finance related data might be required. If anyone can please help here). I hope the reports to some extent must be publicly available.

More suggestions please.